# No video playback when using home sharing on iTunes for Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, video, itunes, home-sharing

I recently configured iTunes Home Sharing on my home network. My WHS server is the central library sharing both my Music and Video files. All my videos are encoded into H.264/MP4 format. All my machines are authorized and has access to Home Sharing. All my machines are running the latest version of iTunes 9.

On my Snow Leopard machines iTunes happily plays the videos and music with no issues.

On the Windows 7 machines however the play button fades for about 2 seconds when selecting a shared video and then nothing happens. The Windows machines are running the latest Community Codec Pack. Music sharing works perfectly on the Windows machines.

When accessing the videos through the native WHS media connect sharing as well as through the file share I can play them perfectly on the Windows 7 machines. When adding the file to the iTunes library on the Windows 7 machine it also plays perfectly.

Any advice, ideas or suggestions as to how to play the videos I have shared through Home Sharing on Windows 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might check this article, to see if everything matches your setup:

[Windows 7 and iTunes Home Sharing](http://www.brighthub.com/computing/windows-platform/articles/77534.aspx)

Comment: Didn't solve my problem but was useful nonetheless.